# Trouble displaying results of foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to get the results of an array and output it in this format:

Author: Kate
Text: This is the text for result 1

Author: Jen
Text: This is the text for result 2

The results return several records and I need to use my first ever FOREACH loop to go through and display them all, but I am having a hard time getting the results to format correctly. I've looked at many website and tried many things and I know the below code is very wrong. Can someone help me figure out what is right?

```
<?php 
foreach ($results){
echo "results->display_name;"<br>"echo "$results->text";
}
?>
```

Comment: how do you want the results formatted? and whats the code that sets the $results variable look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->display_name . "<br>" . $result->text;
}
```